# raspberry pi 2 model B can not connect to the network

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, rasbperrypi, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends:
I am a newer to raspberry pi and to ubuntu.I install ubuntu in raspberry pi 2 model B.The ubuntu is downloaded from the website [link text](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).

I find that the ubuntu is minimal ubuntu-standard version without GUI. I should connect to the network to use the apt-get method to install lxde.But I find that LAN is without driver.Whether  people who use raspberry pi 2 model B with ubuntu face this network problem? And how do you solve it? Please tell me.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207165/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-can-not--connect-to-the-network/) by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your best bet is to post this on the Raspberry Pi forum:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums

---

Originally posted by [corb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20674/corb/) with karma: 339 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1